# dynamic names of matrices in C++ (Armadillo library)

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

I want to generate `k` different random matrices in C++(with Armadillo library) where n is not fix at first and is an input in my function. It is easy in Armadillo to generate random matrices by using the following code within a `for` loop :

```
 mat A = randu<mat>(n,n);
```

But since I need them in the next steps, I have to assign dynamic names or indexes for them, e.g. A1, A2, ... .
I want to know which method is the best one for this case except of using the pointers?

Comment: How about a container, like a `std::vector<mat>`?

Comment: There's really no way to do this, you'll need to use a container. Since you don't know the number of matrices you'll have, a vector is probably your best option

Comment: @Nic could you please mention how I can define my "for" loop in this case by using the vector?

Comment: I don't think a code snippet will really help, I'd recommend looking at a tutorial on vectors

Comment: @aschepler thanks. it works in my case.

Comment: @Nic I used vectors and it works nice in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It might be more convenient (and efficient, but have not tested) to instead use an armadillo cube:

```
cube A = randu<cube>(n,n,k);
```

A single matrix in this cube would then be accessed as `A.slice(i)` with 0 ≤ i ≤ k-1. Just like matrices cubes can be resized at runtime, so you can dynamically change your n and k. You can even preserve old values using `A.resize(n',n',k')`